# Python3 method call returns None despite an explicit return of a new class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection

It's my first post so please go easy on me. Not too easy, of course ;)

Anyway, I'm using Python 3.2.3 to write a text adventure game. There is a class Labyrinth that holds a collection of Location objects, which in turn contain subclasses of GameItem of Actor.

During a turn, Labyrinth polls each of the Locations, which poll their contents, for parser Command objects, which are executed by Labyrinth.doTurn(). Command executions usually result in a subclass of Message being returned by the performing object's action callback.

Anyway, the following code is the relevant snippet from Labyrinth. It retrieves the Message in the 'result' variable:

```
 for command in self._pollLocations():
        if command.getVerb() == 'quit':
            if self._confirmQuit() is True:
                return 2  # status 2 == quit w/o win or loss    
            else:
                print( "Whew! I sure am glad for that!" )
        else:
            print( "^BEFORE" )
            print( "command: %s\tperformer: %s" % ( command.getVerb(), command.performer.getName() ) )
            result = command.performer.execute( command )
            print( "vAFTER"  )
            print( "Got result: %s" % str(result) )

        if result is None:
            print( "Got NONE: returning it" )
            return None

        if isinstance( result, Exception ):
            raise( result )

        if isinstance( result, Message ):
            print( "Found Message instance:" )
            result.write()
            return None
```

However, no matter what I return in the called method's return statements, the above `result =` call always gets None. Here is the Actor.take() method that I'm calling:

```
  def take( self, arg ):
    """
    Take an item in an accessible area.
    """
    item = self.location.getItemByName( arg )
    if isinstance( item, MatchNotFound ):
        print( "Actor.take(): Returning: %s" % str( ThatsNotHereMsg() ) )
        return ThatsNotHereMsg()

    elif isinstance( item, MissingDirectObject ):
        print( "Missing DO" )
        return TellMeWhatToTakeMsg()
    elif isinstance( item, AlgorithmCouldNotDecide):
        print( "Algorthm coul dnot decide." )
        return IndecisionMsg()
    elif isinstance( item, YouShouldNotBeSeeingThisError ):
        print( "Returning GenericGameMsg" )
        return GenericGameMsg( "You should not be seeing this error. "   \
               "The programmer has made a serious mistake "              \
               "and should be beaten for it. Besides, he's "             \
               "a lazy bum who never delivers software on time."         \
        )
    else:
        print( "take: made it past if..elif chain" )

    if item is None:
        print( "item is None: returning TellMeWhatToMakeMsg()" )
        return TellMeWhatToTakeMsg()

    if item.isTakeable( by=self ) is True:
        print( "item.isTakeable: performing take" )
        self.addItem( item )
        self.location.delItem( item )
        return YouTookItMsg()
    print( "take: got to the end. Returning YouJustCantHaveItMsg" )
    return YouJustCantHaveItMsg()
```

Finally, here's the output when I'm running the game. All of those print statements up there are for debugging. You'll see me trying to take a non-existent item to cause MatchNotFound, which should return a new instance of ThatsNotHere, but doesn't.

```
You are in the cavern zone of a natural cave in the East Texas countryside.
You know this cave is unexplored. The deep, dark tunnel lies to the north.
"There's really no turning back now!", you tell yourself.
There is: a shady  character (i.e. you) here.


t1 CavernZone ~> take gold coin 
^BEFORE
command: take   performer: player
Actor.take(): Returning: You don't see that here.
vAFTER
Got result: None
Got NONE: returning it

t2 CavernZone ~>
```

So... my question is, what's going on here? Is my new instance being GC'ed because the function returns before the return value is assigned to the caller? Or something else. I really have no idea, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Peter

EDIT:

As Roland said below, post (and check!) the performer.execute() code. It turns out I forgot to return the result in that function! Thanks for the forehead slap, it turns out I need a lot of those! ;)

```
def execute( self, cmd ):
    if cmd.callback is not None:
        result = eval( cmd.callback )( cmd.getArgs() ) 
    else:
        pass
```

It should read:

```
def execute( self, cmd ):
    if cmd.callback is not None:
        result = eval( cmd.callback )( cmd.getArgs() ) 
    else:
        result = None
    return result
```

So, thanks again for the help!

Here is the output of the program working as planned:

```
t14 CavePassageOne ~> take something
Yes, but what?

t15 CavePassageOne ~> take computer
You don't see that here.
```

Comment: What about simplifying your code by replacing your `if..elif..else` chain with the `isinstance` check with a `get_message` method (or better still a `message` [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property)) in the `Item` class that returns the correct message instance for each `Item`.

Comment: Assuming the `*Msg` functions you call return strings, there doesn't seem to be anything unusual in your code. But we can't see the complete picture. Could you show the code for `command.performer.execute` as well?

Comment: @Pedro: I've simplified the code to just print the message in the take() function instead of passing it up. But, I was trying to plan for more complex situations... The design isn't quite fixed yet.

Comment: @Roland Thanks! That was the key to the puzzle! I forgot to return the result in the execute() function, which I'm going to paste above... Thanks again!

Comment: n.b. the reason I return the *Msg objects instead of just printing messages is because I want to hard-code as little text as possible to make it more customizable. *Msg will return either its `message` or its `__doc__` making it easy to add and change.